# How can i upload multiple folder of vs code in different repository in github?

Tags: flutter, dart, github

in my flutter web project after i hit `flutter web build` , it creates a new web folder under `/build/web/` i upload these folder to github and then use the github pages to host the web pages.

So, currently everytime i have to rebuild the web, i transfer the web folder to an existing folder with a link to github repository, the question is, can't this be done withing the vscode project itself?
To simplify the question, my visual studio project is already being uploaded to github repository, now i want the sub directory (web) of the flutter project to upload in a separate github repository from visual studio code itself
in short
one flutter project needs to create 2 repository in github, main project is uploaded to one repo then a sub folder build/web need to go to another repo. and changes should be made within the vscode itself rather than transferring to a different folder etc.

[image]